# Find a power series that diverges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

The closest I can come is $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty} x^nn!$ which converges only at x=0. Is it possible to come up with one that doesn't converge at $x=0$ nor any $x \in \mathbb{R}$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: A power series to you is what... of the form $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$?  If you plug in $x=0$ to any power series of that form, the only surviving term is $a_0$

Comment: @Karhik: where are $x$ in $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ ? $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$ is not a power series !!

Comment: Neither $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}$ nor $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty n$ qualify as power series since they are not of the form $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If $ \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....$ is a power series then we have always convergence at $x=0$, since for $x=0$ the series reduces to $a_0$, which is trivialy convergent.